# golang regex key:value issue

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to split a syslog message into a key:value 'map[string]string', but cannot seem to get the regex right.

The source string delimits its keys and values by an '='. However, each pair is seperated by spaces with spaces actually being within the values. I have it pretty close but as you can see from the link below, I can't get the rest of the 'start', 'end', or 'suser' values.

Here's [a link](https://play.golang.org/p/7qvmTS3My58) to a golang playground showing my exact problem:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

var rex = regexp.MustCompile("(\\w+)=(.+?[^\\\\s\\\\w+=]+)")

func main() {
    conn := "start=Mar 26 2019 10:36:14 +00:00 end=Mar 26 2019 10:36:14 +00:00 suser=AD.COM\\\\Username src=10.1.0.51"
    data := rex.FindAllStringSubmatch(conn, -1)

    res := make(map[string]string)
    for _, kv := range data {
        k := kv[1]
        v := kv[2]
        res[k] = v
    }
    for v := range res {fmt.Printf("%s: %v\n", v, res[v])}

}
```

Comment: No. In some cases there are many more but the format is always the same. 
k:v[space]k:v[space] etc. I wouldn't rely on the order of these either.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
 var rex = regexp.MustCompile(`(\w+)=([^=]*\w)(?:\s|$)`)
```

See the [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/O3_SecvoZo3), the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/dUd1B8/1) and the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%5Cw%2B)%3D(%5B%5E%3D%5D*%5Cw)(%3F%3A%5Cs%7C%24)).

[image]

**Regex details**

- `(\w+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more word chars
- `=` - a `=` char
- `([^=]*\w)` - Capturing group 2: any 0+ chars other than `=` and then a word char
- `(?:\s|$)` - either a whitespace or end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try the following pattern:

```
(\\s*[^\\s]+)=([^=]*[\\w\\d]+\\s|[\\d.]+)
```

**Result**:

```
start: Mar 26 2019 10:36:14 +00:00 
end: Mar 26 2019 10:36:14 +00:00 
suser: AD.COM\\Username 
src: 10.1.0.51
```

**Example**:

https://play.golang.org/p/R8rE_GGZF_W

Comment: This seems to work great! 
I'm going to go away and test it aginst some larger datasets .

Comment: Okay I have tested your solution with a larger data set and it failed to collect larger data sets that ended with string values. Ammended slightly [here](https://play.golang.org/p/aF9DPBPmNsA). 
Appends `|[\\w+$]` to the end.

Comment: So with your amendment did it work? It looked like all the keys and values were in the output.

Comment: Yeah. With the ammendment It works great! Thank you so much. I was in a bit of a rut.

Comment: You’re welcome! Well, you can accept the answer, you get rep for that.